# Sophix tablet will not work without an SD card

Tags: camera, external-sd

My Sophix tablet was working without the SD card, but now the camera will not work. I get the following error message:

> Insert a SD card before using.

Comment: Were you able to access the camera with out an SD card before? Did you just recently upgrade to Android 4.1? Did anything else change before you started having this issue?

Comment: yes It worked before but no I have not done anything with it. I took a picture and then I went to take another and it said to insert an SD card

Comment: Do you have space available on your tablet?

Comment: Yes I deleted pictures to make sure there was room

Comment: Is there possibly a setting for where to save photos?

Comment: Is your tablet rooted?

Comment: when I go on the settings I cant find how to change them. I go on setting and go on apps and then click on camera and it says that it is saving to my tablet but it is not acting like it is

Comment: idk what that is (rooted) I just got it so I am not sure with all this stuff

Comment: Try installing another camera app such as [Camera MX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magix.camera_mx) or [FX Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ymst.android.fxcamera). Does the issue persist?

Comment: what does that mean ( persist

Comment: an I have already tried to install another one I wil try again

Comment: Persist - Continue to exist; be prolonged.

Comment: yes it is still on there I can get on my camera and then I can click on pictures that I taken but I just cant take any

Comment: THANK YOU sooomuch I tried ur CAMERA MX and I can take pictures thank u

Comment: If it fixed the issue please mark my answer correct so that people with a similar issue that may be searching Android Enthusiasts can find the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

A work around is to install a 3rd party camera app such as [Camera MX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magix.camera_mx) or [FX Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ymst.android.fxcamera).