# My Camera on my android tablet isn't letting me take any pictures. help?

Tags: external-sd, camera

The camera on my Android tablet doesn't let me take any pictures. It says `Insert an SD card before using the camera`.

I didnt need an SD card before. I put an SD card in and it still says the same thing!

Is there a solution to my problem that would help? I already tried the solution proposed in [Sophix tablet will not work without an SD card](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/41813/16575), but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: but it worked before i needed the sd card in and i deleted some photos but still wouldn't let me take any photos

Comment: You have the same problem as the guy in the question I shared. Perhaps it might help if you tried the unaccepted answer.

Comment: i have already tried that but it doesn't solve the problem i'm having on the tablet

Comment: Well, while the answer reads "it helps to install a 3rd party camera app", that's only half of the solution -- it doesn't change the behaviour of the original camera app. Have you tried taking photos with one of the replacements? (Might sound stupid, but I've seen strange things already -- so my apologies in advance! :)

Comment: yes i have tried that but still doesn't work i delteed pictures aswel and it still says need to insert and sd card before i use the camera and iv'e put an micro sd card in but still didn't work

Comment: i have resetted everything and its still not working plus it now nothing works on it, it says 'unfortunately settings have stopped' :(

Comment: That looks very much as if you're at a point to do a [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info)

Comment: And which tablet is this?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, but I use AVG free antivirus privacy options to wipe out (format) my sd card, then restart my tablet. Problem solved (can take pictures again)